# wp_content text length and displaying 'more' for the full text

Tags: the-content

(Using wordpress)I tried to find out what's the php code to display the length text of content and likely a clickable 'more' under the content to display my full content when somebody click (like in this picture - [image] ) but unfortunately I couldn't do it, this is the code I tried out so far:

```
$character == 40;

if (mb_strlen( get_the_content() < $character)

( have_posts() ) ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

the_content();

else{

the_content('Continue Reading...')

}
```

I highly think my code is not right, so if theres somebody out there to take a eye on and tell me if my code is incorrect or there's a other way to do this this I'd appreciate it alot :).
Thanks in return!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop use this:

`<p><?php $excerpt = get_the_content(); if (strlen($excerpt) > 255) { $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 255) . "..."; echo $excerpt; } ?></p>`

Here get_the_content() will grab all the content but substr function will cut it down to 255, you can put any number you want.

Cheers !!!